# Write text inside UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to do something really simple, but i dont know how to do it with obj c. I want to write string "hello world" inside the CAShapeLayer that my UIBezierPath is using as shape. can you please show me how that is done by code??  i just want to write this string inside the shape

i have this UIBezierPath down below:
 `UIBezierPath* oval2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: oval2Rect];`

inside my viewcontroller and dont know how to add text into it

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do this in a subclass of UIView? You can do it like:

```
-(void)drawRect{
    UIBezierPath* oval2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: self.bounds];
    [oval2Path addClip];
    [@"Hello World" drawInRect:self.bounds withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.bounds.size.height]}];
}
```

Comment: This will just mask the text with the ellipse. I don't believe it will wrap the text to the shape of the ellipse, if that's what you're going for.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg the question is pretty vague. But wrapping two words to fit a shape seems to make less sense that what I've done. You know it's possible to just supply your own answer without commenting on others, if you feel they'er incorrect.

Comment: i'm trying to avoid using drawRect

Comment: @heneriklarsen because?

Answer (score 0):

I found a few tutorials ([1](http://blog.amyworrall.com/post/11098565269/text-wrap-with-core-text), [2](http://robnapier.net/wrapping-text-around-shape-with-coretext)) to do this with Core Text, but it appears you can also do it with a `UITextView` and TextKit as of iOS 7:

```
UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = ...; // some bezier path
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];
```

(TextKit solution cribbed from [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial).)

Comment: could you provide full example please

Answer (score 0):

Here i am creating some circle using bezier path and text also

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArcs.count; i++) {
    NSInteger startAngele   =   i * 360/numberOfArcs.count+270;
    NSInteger endAngele;
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

        [bezierPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2.0, self.bounds.size.width/2.0) radius:0.25  * self.bounds.size.width startAngle:degreesToRadians(startAngele) endAngle:degreesToRadians(endAngele) clockwise:YES];
    }
```

you write text on bezier path using CAShapelayer and CATextlayer use this code

```
         CAShapeLayer *progressLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        [progressLayer setPath:bezierPath.CGPath];


        CATextLayer* text = [CATextLayer new];
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfArcs.count; i++) {
        text.string =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
        text.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef _Nullable)([UIFont fontWithName:@"akaChen" size:42]);
        text.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef _Nullable)([UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]);
        text.fontSize=25;
        text.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);
        text.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(progressLayer.frame) ,CGRectGetMidY(progressLayer.frame) );

        CGFloat vert = CGRectGetMidY(progressLayer.frame) / CGRectGetHeight(text.frame);

        text.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, vert );
        text.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
        text.foregroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

       [progressLayer addSublayer:text];
    }
```